# How to use container class and my wrappper together Bootstrap 3?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

how can I use my own fixed size wrapper and responsive container class from Bootstrap. When I use together and responsive is lost 
My example code :

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 col-ms-12">
                <p>Всеки дом са нуждае от малко Коледна магия и ние имаме идеалната рецепта. Трябват ви само: 1 бр красиво украсена елха, щипка светещи лампички, малко декорация и много подаръци за твоите близки под елхата. Разгледай нашите промоционални предложения и се подгответе за най-магически празник
                    от годината.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
.wrapper {
width: 980px;
margin: 0 auto;
```

}

class Container is defined by Bootstrap
Thanks!

Comment: use !important for width in wrapper width: 980px !important;

Comment: Why not just add the relevant properties to `container` and forget about `wrapper`?

Comment: However doing anything like this means your application will not be responsive and will not work well on a mobile device.

Answer (score 4):

The problem you have with your wrapper class is that it is going to break the responsive nature of Bootstrap. The best solution would be to customise the Bootstrap library directly.

Just visit http://getbootstrap.com/customize/ and play with the `Container sizes` there.

Answer (score 2):

Put the wrapper around the container, you are literally wanting to wrap a Bootstrap container with your wrapper, so literally doing that should achieve what you want.

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-ms-12">
            <p>Всеки дом са нуждае от малко Коледна магия и ние имаме идеалната рецепта. Трябват ви само: 1 бр красиво украсена елха, щипка светещи лампички, малко декорация и много подаръци за твоите близки под елхата. Разгледай нашите промоционални предложения и се подгответе за най-магически празник
                от годината.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want disable responsive for all containers in site:
1. Omit the viewport `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`
2. Override the width on the .container for each grid tier with a single width, for example width: 970px !important; Be sure that this comes after the default Bootstrap CSS. You can optionally avoid the !important with media queries or some selector-fu.
3. If using navbars, remove all navbar collapsing and expanding behavior.
4. For grid layouts, use .col-xs-* classes in addition to, or in place of, the medium/large ones. Don't worry, the extra-small device grid scales to all resolutions.

Comment: This is not and answer, you are just guiding him to link